# Why Outlook is not getting synchronized

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am developing a C# application that uses Outlook COM object library. 
After adding the appointment to the calendar, it is immediately shown in Outlook desktop application but the appointment is not found at Outlook web application. The miserable thing is that some appointments got synchronized and it stopped synchronizing suddenly. 
Here's how I saved the appointment:

```
Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

string profile = "";
mapiNS.Logon(profile, null, null, null);

Outlook.AppointmentItem apt = olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
apt.Save();
```

How can I make it get synchronized?

Comment: Microsoft made a f**** change into Outlook COM recently. Are you sure your application is the same processor set as your Outlook? I mean, if your Outlook is x32 your code *must* be utilizing the same settings for compilation.

Comment: My app is compiling with "any CPU" i.e. x64. But it compiles and runs successfully and the appointment is added to desktop outlook, but it is not synchronized along the internet.

Comment: I have here problems using app "any CPU" and Outlook 2013/Office 365 - and it always had functioned perfectly. I had to compile different versions to get all functioning again. And seeing your code, you need to set up the LOGON with all data related to MAPI, doesn't it?

Comment: When I add appointments from within the Outlook itself, the problem is again there.

Comment: Try to run a recent OfficeFix tool from MS. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 0):

I had to call send method after the save method, otherwise the Outlook sends the appointment whenever it wants.

```
Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

string profile = "";
mapiNS.Logon(profile, null, null, null);

Outlook.AppointmentItem apt = olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
apt.Save();
apt.Send();
```